# Confused in 2D random array number generation using c++

Tags: arrays, c++11

I was using the following code to generate two 2D random arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>
#include <new>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{

  std::default_random_engine generator,generator2;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution;
  double **peta, **pxi;
  const int Nmodes =200;
  const double PI=3.1415926;

  peta = new double*[3];
  pxi = new double*[3];
  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
      peta[i] = new double[Nmodes];
      pxi[i] = new double[Nmodes];
    }

  distribution.param(std::normal_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0).param());

  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
      for (int j=0; j<Nmodes; ++j)
        {
          peta[i][j]=distribution(generator);
          // pxi[i][j] =distribution(generator2);  //1st case
        }
      for (int j=0; j<Nmodes; ++j)
        {
           pxi[i][j] =distribution(generator2); //2nd case
        }
    }
  std::cout<<std::setprecision(15)<<"peta "<<peta[0][20]<<'+'<<peta[1][20]<<'+'<<peta[2][20]<<'+'<<peta[2][30]<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"pxi "<<pxi[0][20]<<"+"<<pxi[1][20]<<'+'<<pxi[2][20]<<'+'<<pxi[2][30]<<std::endl;



    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)    
{
      delete [] peta[i];
      delete [] pxi[i];
    }
  delete [] peta;
  delete [] pxi;

  return 0;
}
```

In above code,I generated peta and pxi 2d arrays. In the first case I wrote them together in the nested for loops while in the second case I wrote them separately for the second loop (please see the comment region in the code). For the case 1, peta and pxi are different but they the are the same in case 2. **I think they should be the same because the generators are equivalent even they are different variables**.  I used gcc 4.8.4 with -std=c++11 option to compile. 
     Does anyone know the reason? I appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: Sorry i have not finished the description. I complete the question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding what your question is. What about the results is confusing?

Comment: I rewrite the problem and highlight the confused parts.

Comment: @rewish You maybe want to create a class to handle theses `double**` data types. That's how you should handle ressources in C++ : [How do i allocate multi dimensional arrays using new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#multidim-arrays) and [But the previous FAQ’s code is SOOOO tricky and error prone! Isn’t there a simpler way?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#multidim-arrays2) . It's the best way to avoid memory leaks. See also : [Why should I use container classes rather than simple arrays?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#arrays-are-evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical implementation of `std::normal_distribution` implements [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) - an algorithm that produces normally distributed numbers in pairs. So the first time you call it, it produces a pair of numbers and returns the first one, saving the second one for later. The second time you call it, it returns that saved number. The third time you call it, it again produces two numbers; lather, rinse repeat.

Thus, your first case never actually uses `generator2`. `distribution(generator)` call manufactures two numbers - one goes into `peta`, the other into `pxi`.

In the second case, `peta` is populated from `generator` and `pxi` from `generator2`. You don't seed either of them, which means they both start with the same seed (whatever the default is), and both produce the same random sequence. So you end up with the same values in both arrays.

Comment: It looks like both the first and second case use `generator2` to me.

Comment: @DanielH Not really. Like I said, `distribution(generator)` call produces two numbers, and returns the first one. The following `distribution(generator2)` call just returns the second number cached from prior call, without actually using `generator2`.

Comment: Oh, I see; I got confused between the different components. So if `Nmodes` were odd the arrays would be different either way, but in the second case they’d be just offset by one?

Comment: @lgor: I see. By the way,  where can I find such explanation of a function for c++ library?

Comment: @rewish Well, I can't think of a place where this might be documented. I don't remember where I learned about that two-at-a-time algorithm; it's been a while. `std::normal_distribution` is not required to use this algorithm (so it wouldn't be spelled out in the C++ standard) - it's just that most implementations do that because it's the most efficient way.